# why does only the last expr in a lambda block get evaluated?

Tags: scheme

I wrote this following simple piece of scheme just to see whether Scheme is doing dynamic or static binding.

Now I was expecting line 17 `(myFunc 5 6)` to evaluate to `56` (because I know Scheme has static-scoping).
But when I execute the code, all I get is `6` (without the `5`) which makes no sense!

Could anyone please tell me what makes it print only `6`?

```
 2(define myFunc
 3  (lambda (a b)
 4    (define aref
 5      (lambda ()
 6        a))
 7    (define bref
 8      (lambda ()
 9        b))
10    (define innerFunc
11      (lambda (a b)
12        (aref)
13        (bref)))
14
15    (innerFunc 1 2)))
16
17(myFunc 5 6)
```

Comment: ALL expressions inside the lambda are evaluated. The *result* is the result of the last expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of a `lambda` is implicitly inside a `begin` form. And a `begin` returns the value of the last expression. So this:

```
((lambda () 1 2 3))
```

Will evaluate to the same value as this:

```
(begin 1 2 3)
```

... Which is the number `3`. Now if you need to *simultaneously* return two or more values try this (works in Racket):

```
(values 1 2 3)
=> 1
   2
   3
```

Comment: Ooooh! I DID NOT KNOW THAT!  (I swear I've been writing Scheme (on an off) for almost 3 years now, and I REALLY did not notice this!). Thanks!!!!

Comment: So how do I make it return both 5 and 6?

Comment: If you need to return two or more _simultaneous_ values, you can use `(values 1 2)`

Comment: So that'd be `(values (aref) (bref))`? Great! Thank you agaiN! :) (Learnt a GREAT thing today!) I would give you +10, if I could.

Comment: Returning multiple-values can only occur in some contexts.  For example, you can't write `(let ((stuff (values 1 2))) …)`  One place multiple-values are allowed is the interactive read-eval-print loop; others are `call-with-values,` `define-values,` `let-values,` and `let*-values.`

Comment: I didn't really mean "return". (Obviously, a function can only return one value). What I meant was how to combine the output of multiple expressions in a lambda block. And luckily, Oscar Lopez was able to see what I meant. :)

Comment: @OneTwoThree actually, `values` _does_ return multiple values, so special care must be taken to handle them, as pointed by @GoZoner. If you just want to return the combined result of multiple expressions, an even simpler solution would be to pack them in a list: `(list (aref) (bref))`